# as per javaScript what is the size of a,b, and c here?

Tags: javascript, size

```
let a=4;

const b=5;

var c=6;
```

As per javaScript, what is the size of `a`, `b`, and `c` here?

Comment: Size? What do you mean?

Comment: Clarify what do you mean by size. If you are talking about size of a number - "In JavaScript, Number is a numeric data type in the double-precision 64-bit floating point format (IEEE 754)"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Number